# Enforcing rsa_pkcs1_sha256 in gRPC C++ mutual authentication: any available option within the classes?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, rsa, grpc

I am attempting to implement mutual authentication between a client and a server using gRPC C++. Specifically, I aim to enforce the use of the rsa_pkcs1_sha256 algorithm on the server, as it is supported. However, when the connection is established normally, the signature algorithm defaults to "rsa_pss_pss_sha256." How can I compel the server to utilize rsa_pkcs1_sha256 from the gRPC client's side?

I have thoroughly searched the gRPC documentation but have been unable to find any relevant information. Is there a configuration option available within the gRPC classes that can address this issue?